# Unwanted commas while I am trying to pass HTML code and some variables

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script, jquery-confirm

I am working on a **Photoshop [CEP](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP) extension** and I am using **[jquery-confirm](http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/)** for my alerts. My problem is that I get some **unwanted commas** while I am trying to pass an **HTML table** and some **variables** to a **jquery-confirm alert**!!! Here is the code which is responsible for this part...

```
function list_FoundLayers() {
  try {
    // Checks if should get layers data by layer name and HEX color or not.
    let layersData;
    if (htmlElements.content.specificNameTxtbox.value === "") {
      layersData = filter_layersData(false)
    } else {
      layersData = filter_layersData(true)
    };

    // Creates a table row for each layer.
    let tableRows = [];
    for (let i in layersData) {
      let hasEffect;
      if (layersData[i][3] === 'true') {
        hasEffect = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>'
      } else {
        hasEffect = '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>'
      };
      let isVisible;
      if (layersData[i][4] === 'true') {
        isVisible = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>'
      } else {
        isVisible = '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>'
      };
      let tableRow = `<tr id="jc-table-layer-data-${i}" layerID="${layersData[i][1]}" class="inner-row">
                                <td>${layersData[i][1]}</td>
                                <td>${layersData[i][5]}</td>
                                <td>${layersData[i][0]}</td>
                                <td>${hasEffect}</td>
                                <td>${isVisible}</td>
                            </tr>`;
      tableRows.push(tableRow);
    };

    // Creates the whole HTML table.
    let htmlCode = `<table class="jc-table" id="jc-table"><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Type</th><th>Name</th><th>FX</th><th>Visible</th></tr><tfoot><tr><td colspan="5">Found <b>${tableRows.length}</b> layers in total.</td></tr></tfoot><tbody>${tableRows}</tbody></table>`

    // Gives result using a jquery-confirm.
    commonAlert(
      'blue',
      null,
      'Found Layers',
      htmlCode,
      function() {
        manipulateHTMLElements('disable')
      },
      function() {
        for (let i in layersData) {
          const $thisElement = $(`#jc-table-layer-data-${i}`);
          const $thisElementBackgroundColor = $($thisElement).css('backgroundColor');

          // Select specific layer when user click on it.
          $($thisElement).click(
            function() {
              $(this).css('background', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)');
              selectById($(this).attr("layerID"))
            }
          )
          // When user click anywhere else.
          $(document).mouseup(
            function(element) {
              if (!$thisElement.is(element.target) && $thisElement.has(element.target).length === 0) {
                $($thisElement).css('background', $thisElementBackgroundColor)
              }
            }
          )
        };
      },
      function() {
        this.close()
      },
      function() {
        manipulateHTMLElements('enable')
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    catchJSErrorAlert(getStack(err.stack, 'fullStuck'), getStack(err.stack, 'fnName'), getStack(err.stack, 'fileName'), getStack(err.stack, 'lnNum'), getStack(err.stack, 'colNum'), err.name, err.message);
  };
};
```

And **[here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pww-0LaHpAWX_wMFtLV8no5WnTbjZiDw)** is an image of the issue.

Comment: Commas suggest array.join() without a parameter or array.toString() But it's possible problem is not in your code - you have 9 rows in screenshot while I can see only 8 commas.

Comment: @Zydnar so, it may be an issue of jquery-confirm?

Comment: It's just quick quess - I can't see any loops, map, forEach, join etc. in your code.

Comment: Sorry - I made mistake - if array is of lengh 9 it has 8 commas after .join() I'm sleeping today. As workaround - you can remove commas from your element after creating the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noticed by Zydna, you need to make a string out of your tableRows...

```
<tbody>${tableRows.join('\n')}</tbody> //\n not necessary but help to debug...
```

also I think you forgot to close the `<thead>` tag in your html line.

Comment: Solved!!! And yes, you are right, I forgot to close <thead>. Thank you very much!!! :D